# getting the dynamic ID value from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have created dynamic id for a <`slect`> . Here is the code -

```
    <% int i = 0; %>

    <c:forEach var="pro" items="${proofingListsWithRoles.allList}" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
            <td id="jobId">${pro.jobId}</td>
            <td>                            
                <select id="selectRole<%=i %>" onchange="javascript:selectRole('selectRole<%=i %>')">
                    <c:forEach items="${pro.roles}" var="rol" varStatus="status">
                        <option value="${rol.id}"> <c:out value="${rol.name}"/></option>
                    </c:forEach>                
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% i++; %>
    </c:forEach>
```

Now my target is to find out which id of the selected role from `dropdown.The following`alert()`print selectRoel0, selectRole1, selectRole2,... . Notice selectRole0, selectRole1 etc are id of <select>`. Since `<slect>` is in a forEach loop there are multiple `<select>`. Here inside the function(selectId){} `seelctId` is used get the value of selectRole0,selectRole1 .... and so on.So using the id of `<select>` inside function selectRole(selectId){} how can get which role is selected from the `dropdown`.

```
function selectRole(selectId){
    alert(selectId);
}
```

Comment: Those need to be posted to a server for processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following inside the function.

```
$('#' + selectId).val();
```

Comment: @PeterKA thanks a lot. I am aslo looking for such a solution. But can you please explain a bit how the thing work so that novice like me can understand it while reading it. I also try things like this with **document.getById(selectId).val()** but did not give me the solution.

Comment: @HishamHisham, I'm glad to know that this is helpful to you too. String concatenation is really very straight-forward: `'string1' + 'string2'` gives you `string1string2` ... in this case though `5` (numeric) is first cast into string.

Comment: If you want to use a `DOM` element you would have to stick to `DOM` methods and properties: `document.getElementById(....).value`. You can do `$(domElement).val()` but not `domElement.val()`